# How to switch Camera Defocus on 1 object to another?

Tags: animation

Is there a way to Defocus on 2 objects vice versa without affecting transition? Camera is in motion, showing first as blurred second as focus object. I need to switch to first from second. First must be focus slowly while the other/second object is slowly blurring. Do I have to use 2 cameras for this? If so ho do i retain the same focus of the camera with the second camera? I'm using Cycles Render Blender 2.79...

Comment: you could focus on an empty and move the empty?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using an empty as the focus target, then animate the empty from one location to another over time.